# Using USB-Keyboard (connected my mbp) to control IPad via Bluetooth Connection

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, ipad

Hey guys I wonder if there is a way (a third-party solution maybe?) to control my IPad with the keyboard thats connected to my mbp.

Someone else on Stackexchange also asked [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4437/using-pc-mac-keyboard-as-a-bluetooth-keyboard-for-iphone) for this feature (Nov 2010) back then there was no other way but jailbreak the Device (whats not possible right now for the IPad 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible to control a non-jailbroken iPad in the way you've described.

Out of curiosity, is there a reason it has to be an external USB keyboard and not the keyboard built into the MacBook Pro itself?

Perhaps if you mention why you'd like this functionality (e.g. game control? typing into a notepad app?), someone could propose an alternative.  The Ask Different users can be quite creative when questions are worded broadly enough.  :]

Comment: Hey Austin, I am thinking about different use cases. The first would be to use the IPad as a dedicated device for social media activities (like facebook, twitter, and so on) and would love to use it to publish messages really quick.

In the end I guess that a dedicated bluetooth keyboard would be the best solution, but right now I am just curious what can be done :)

Comment: @Gregory Understood -- it's always fun to push the boundaries of our gadgets!  :]

Answer (score 0):

Here you go Sir not free but it does the job you need
[iTunes Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ikeyboard/id441439411?mt=12)

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.